# How to create a generic type function to fetch data from an API in Rust?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-cargo, yew

I would like to fetch data from a backend API in my Yew based on a certain datatype, that is my model.

I have managed to do the job based on a tutorial on yew.rs: https://yew.rs/docs/tutorial
After that I wanted to create a generic type function to fetch data based on my model(s) and I ran into problems.
Here is my model:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use yew::Properties;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Properties, Default)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
}
```

Here is the code from the tutorial that works:

```
    let users: UseStateHandle<Vec<User>> = use_state(|| vec![]);
    {
        let users = users.clone();
        use_effect_with_deps(move |_| {
            let users = users.clone();
            wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
                let fetched_users: Vec<User> = Request::get(&format!("{BACKEND}/users/all"))
                    .send()
                    .await
                    .unwrap()
                    .json()
                    .await
                    .unwrap();
                users.set(fetched_users);
            });
            || ()
        }, ());
    }
```

Here is the function I tried to build:

```
fn fetch_data_try<T: serde::de::DeserializeOwned + 'static>(handle: &UseStateHandle<T>, path: &str) -> UseStateHandle<T>{
    let handle = handle.clone();
    let path = path.clone();
    {
        let handle = handle.clone();
        use_effect_with_deps(move |_| {
            let handle = handle.clone();
            wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
                let fetched_data: T = Request::get(path)
                    .send()
                    .await
                    .unwrap()
                    .json()
                    .await
                    .unwrap();
                handle.set(fetched_data);
            });
            || ()
        }, ());
    }
    handle
}
```

I call it here:

```
let users: UseStateHandle<Vec<User>> = use_state(|| vec![]);
let users = fetch_data_try::<Vec<User>>(&users, &format!("{BACKEND}/users/all"));
```

It gives an error with the path &str variable. When I remove it it compiles, but does not work.
Here is the error:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
   --> frontend/src/app.rs:99:13
    |
92  |   fn fetch_data_try<T: serde::de::DeserializeOwned + 'static>(handle: &UseStateHandle<T>, path: &str) -> UseStateHandle<T>{
    |                                                                                           ----  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
    |                                                                                           |
    |                                                                                           `path` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
...
99  | /             wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
100 | |                 let fetched_data: T = Request::get(path)
101 | |                     .send()
102 | |                     .await
...   |
107 | |                 handle.set(fetched_data);
108 | |             });
    | |              ^
    | |              |
    | |______________`path` escapes the function body here
    |                argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Thank you for the help.